# why is there a crash when class member contains "std::shared_ptr<std::thread>"?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared

I found that my app will crash when class member contains "std::shared_ptr". For example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class Derived {
public:
    Derived() {
        mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&Derived::callback, this);
    }
    ~Derived() { }

    void callback() {}

    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> mThread;
};

int main() {
    Derived * base = new Derived();
    delete base;
    return 0
}
```

I would like to know why?

Comment: Your program triggers a call to `std::terminate`, by way of [destroying a joinable `thread` object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread). You must `join` or `detach` it before destroying.

Comment: Try removing the shared_ptr and see if it changes anything.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want to wait for the thread to finish executing in `~Derived`? If so, why not code that?

Comment: Not at all related to your immediate problem, but beware that copies of a `Derived` object will not have `callback` invoked on *them*. They will only point to a thread that operates on their originator.

Answer (score 3):

When you are starting threads then you must *join* or *detach* them before thread's destructor gets called. I propose to do this in a destructor:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class Derived
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        mThread = std::make_shared<std::thread>(&Derived::callback, this);
    }
    ~Derived()
    {
        if(mThread->joinable())
            mThread->join();
    }
    void callback() {}
    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::thread> mThread;
};

int main()
{
    Derived * base = new Derived();
    delete base;
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, using **shared_ptr** in your example is not necessary. You can simply define **thread** variable:

```
thread mThread;
```

Start new thread:

```
mThread = std::thread(&Derived::callback, this);
```

And join it, when you need:

```
mThread.join();
```

Comment: If you have a shared pointer, the class is assumed to be  copied, only the last instance should join.

Comment: @JVApen Ok )) There was no mention of copying class in the task.

Comment: Yes, I find it. I need call detach() or join() before thread's destructor. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a design flaw, as you use shared_ptr for the thread without guaranteeing ownership of Derived.

As indicated by snake_style, you should join your thread.

I'm gonna argue that you should store the thread by value in your class to guarantee lifetime of Derived:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>

class Derived {
 public:
    Derived() {
        mThread = std::thread(&Derived::callback, this);
}
~Derived() { 
        if (mThread.joinable())
              mThread.join();
}

    void callback() {}

    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }

private:
    std::thread mThread;
};
```

The if-statement in the Dtor protects you from incorrect behavior when Derived gets moved.

Another way of guaranteeing ownership is putting Derived in the thread:

```
 thread = std::thread([d = Derived{}]() mutable { d.callback(); };
```

This moves the thread variable out of the class.

A third solution could be putting Derived in a shared_ptr and using an alias constructor of shared_ptr to create the threads shared pointer. I don't work this out as this might be too tricky and you could as well put the shared_ptr as capture in your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the thread in a shared_ptr it would be better to create a factory function with a shared_ptr custom deleter which joins the thread.

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<std::thread> makeThread(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
                                        , [](std::thread* t) { t->join(); delete t; });
}

void test(std::int32_t &v)
{
    for (int workload = 0; workload < 64; ++workload)
        ++v;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    std::int32_t v = 0;
    auto sptr_thread = makeThread(test, std::ref(v));
    std::cout << "value before exiting: " << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Unlike the std::shared_ptr constructors, std::make_shared does not allow a custom deleter.
I would prefer the factory as it's not possible to forget joining the thread